# SwiftUI .searchable Modifier and hidden search bar

Tags: swift, list, swiftui, searchable

I'm unsure if SwiftUI `.searchable` modifier is intended to offer this functionality, but I saw some tutorials in which the search bar will first appear when you pull down the List.

So far, I found no way to get this to work. My search bar is always visible from the beginning, but I want to let it appear when you scroll the list.

Here is my demo code - which will always show the search bar. Is there any way to hide it at the initial start?

Here is the full code

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    let names = ["Holly", "Josh", "Rhonda", "Yvonne", "Lucy", "Tim", "Steve", "Sandy", "Bob", "Brian"]
    @State private var searchText = ""

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List(searchResults.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                Text("\(searchResults[index])")
            }
            .searchable(text: $searchText)
        }
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        
    }

    var searchResults: [String] {
        if searchText.isEmpty {
            return names
        } else {
            let filteredNames = names.filter { $0.contains(searchText) }
            return filteredNames.isEmpty ? names : filteredNames
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

> My search bar is always visible from the beginning

… because you attached it to the navigation stack.

Attach it to the `List`

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
        List(searchResults.indices, id: \.self) { index in
            Text("\(searchResults[index])")
        }
        .searchable(text: $searchText)
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem() {
                Button("Test", action: {})
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Content")
    }
    .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
}
```

Comment: I already tested this, and it does not work.

Comment: I tested it too, and it worked. There must be another reason which is beyond the given code.

Comment: Interesting, I added the full code above. Mine doesn't work - wonder why. I'm on 16.4 simulator and device showing the same issue.

Comment: This code does work as intended. But the reason it works is because of the ".navigationTitle("Content")" modifier. Without the NavigationTitle the search bar will be shown instead. This is an unintuitive nuance of the search bar.